# How to switch between input languages using non-standard shortcut on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, language

How can I configure Windows to use keys on the right side of the keyboard to switch input languages? I'd prefer to use **right** `Alt + Shift`, or even better, both **left and right** pairs of `Alt + Shift`.

I did this in my previous OS installation but can't remember how I did it. Maybe I need to use third-party software?

Comment: Only have 8.1 right now, but it was easier on 7:
http://www.7tutorials.com/how-change-keyboard-input-language

Comment: No option here to use **right** `Alt + Shift`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) software.

### Step 1 - Install Software

- Go to https://www.autohotkey.com/
- Download and install the software
  *note: you cannot run this software without a script

### Step 2 - Create a script

- Right click anywhere on your desktop, hover on "new", click "Text Document"
- Open the document and add this text to it
  `RALT::LALT`
- Save the document and then rename it to something with .ahk
  e.g.
  `languageInput.ahk`
- Double click the script to run it

Now the right alt should behave the same as the left alt.
You can also add this script to the startup folder to make it run every time windows starts.

### Step 3 - Copy and Paste into Startup folder

- Right click on the script and select copy or cut
- Paste it into the following location
  `C:\Users\*yourUserName*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: No problem, glad i could help.

Comment: But when I'm connected to remote host via RDP, and press `right alt` the keystroke are sent two times - one as `left alt` and another one as `right alt`. When I use right pair `alt + shift` to switch language, remote host receives simultaneously `left alt + right alt + shift`, switches language and opens menu. When I press `right alt` to leave menu it receives two `alt`s again and... returns back to menu. It is enraging me. So, have to find another way...

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Control Panel"
Click "Clock, Language, and Region"
Click "Change Keyboards or Other Input Methods"
Click "Change Keyboards..." button
Go to "Advanced Key Settings" tab
Here you can change the key stroke options between input languages or for a specific language.
[image]

Comment: There is no choice to use **right** `Alt + Shift`. It doesn't help me. Unfortunately. I was in this menu...

Comment: You could change to ctrl + shift which would work on the right side.

Comment: Omg, all my life I'm using Alt. It is so easy, why I can't use my fave combination?

Comment: Probably for the same reason that Windows can't spit out monoaural audio. It should be so easy.